# How to track numbers of iOS app uninstalls?

Tags: ios, app-store, appsflyer

I've been trying to monitor the numbers of uninstall but couldn't find a reliable way.

1. I tried to check with APNS status but apple doesn't provide any
   status in response.
2. I tried to find any API (to get number of uninstalls) provided by
   apple but still no luck.
3. I started tracking for inactive users but it still is not 100%
   accurate and it only gives me inactive users.
4. There is no delegate method which fires when the app is being deleted.
5. No uninstall information in appstore sales and trends as well.

Later I checked AppsFlyer is providing this capability to track numbers of uninstalls.

Can anyone explain how reliable is AppsFlyer uninstall tracking and why ?

Comment: You can check  AppsFlyer documentation.https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032066-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-iOS

Comment: Hi @A.H.Nuri I know how to integrate AppsFlyer, But I don't know how they track. I've a slight idea that they are sending silent notification but I'm not sure and they haven't mentioned anywhere that which method they are using to track uninstalls

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no official method from Apple to track app uninstalls — this would have user privacy implications, and Apple has built their reputation around protecting user privacy. Given the [history of public outrage](https://techcrunch.com/2017/04/23/uber-responds-to-report-that-it-tracked-users-who-deleted-its-app/) around this sort of tracking, it's unlikely Apple will ever allow it.

AppsFlyer (and other companies that claim to provide 'uninstall tracking') use silent push notifications to do it. Essentially, they ping the device regularly and report an 'uninstall' if the push notification is not successfully delivered.

There are a couple of major issues with this approach:

1. **It's unreliable.** If the user doesn't allow push notifications, or turns them off at some point after installation, you'll get drowned in false positives.
2. **It's against Apple's rules.** The [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) say this:

> **4.5.4** Push Notifications must not be required for the app to function, and should not be used for advertising, promotions, or direct marketing purposes or to send sensitive personal or confidential information. Abuse of these services may result in revocation of your privileges.

AppsFlyer actually got in some [public hot water for this product](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-10-22/now-apps-can-track-you-even-after-you-uninstall-them) last year, and I've heard through the grapevine that Apple intends to crack down on similar services at some point in the near future.

Ultimately, an uninstall is little different from a user who has the app installed but never engages with it. You're probably better off focusing your efforts on building an awesome user experience that improves acquisition and retention, rather than worrying about how to measure a metric that is specifically on Apple's blacklist.

Comment: Just for transparency I'm from the AppsFlyer tech team, and the response above is only partially accurate. 1. Tracking uninstalls is only made possible by applications that enable this functionality, and is not unique to AppsFlyer. 2. Doing so is at the discretion of the user and needs to be manually configured, and is aligned with industry best practices [on privacy](https://www.appsflyer.com/services-privacy-policy) - you can read more about how to do this [here](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/210289286-Uninstall-Measurement#Introduction). 3. To learn more about how to confi

Comment: @Alex great answer

Comment: Not push notification, but they would be using push notification feedback service. Other than this I would also say that silent push notification will still work if all notifications are turned off.

Answer (score 7):

Now Apple offer this information:

> Deletions
>
> See how many users remove your app from devices running iOS 12.3 or later. Measure App Deletions to better understand how users react to changes in your app, such as content updates, price adjustments, or crashes. Compare App Deletions by sources or groups of users to see which types of users are more likely to uninstall your app.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/analytics/

Comment: Thanks for the link. DOnt know why this was downvoted

Comment: Currently this can be found in Analytics > Sources > All > Deletions (bottom item in select list)

Comment: Note that this only provides information for users that have opted-in to offer analytics to app developers. So the number is not reliable.

Answer (score 7):

The current path in Oct 2021 to check out deletions in [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/) is shown as below:

[image]

Note,

1. That is the number of times your app has been deleted on devices running **iOS 12.3**, tvOS 13.0, or macOS 10.15.1 **or later**.
2. Deletions **only** includes data from users who have agreed to share their diagnostics and usage information with app developers.

Comment: Yes Good  great !!

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
2. Select your app
3. Go to Analytics
4. Go to Source
5. Select deletion in right side dropdown
   [image]

Comment: Is there any other way to get it programmatically than making scraping to apple web?